# Rails where to put API calls so it doesn't slow down the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I current have a loop in my **show.html.erb**, and within each loop it's making the following call

```
<p> The above tweet is <%= (Indico.sentiment_hq(tweet.text)*100).round(2)%>% positive</p>
```

Although this works perfectly, it really does slow down the application a lot. With each loop I am calling a new `Indico.sentiment_hq()`, which really is not ideal.

What is the rails way to call the same API repeatedly? I thought about storing it in the model, but was wondering if there are any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using sidekiq and store the results inside the db and just read it in the view, this way you will speed up your application and also reduce the calls to the API.

it doesn't make sense to call the API each time the view is rendered.

references:

sidekiq - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

api calls sidekiq - https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/delay-api-calls-to-twilio-with-rails-active-job-and-sidekiq.html